# How to put the custom check box on the left side of UITableview with multiple selection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to implement the uitableview selection with the design similar to the underseen design.
Please let me know how to accomplish this.

[image]

Comment: use imageview, and change based on selection,For mulltiselection enable their property, there is a lot of thing regarding this

Comment: please post a code it will be helpful for me. I am new

Answer (score 1):

The best way for implementing checkbox is, you can take button and toggle the image.UIButton is a subclass of UIController,which has a selected property. You can use this property to toggle the on/off behaviour of a checkbox

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom class of UITableview cell
2. Add number of buttons you wants on the cell
3. Give class name of UITableViewCell to the cell of tale view
4. Connect IB_Outlates of Buttons
5. In the delegate cellForRowAtIndexpath

   ```
   myButton.tag = indexPath.row
    [cell.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shippingBtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    - (void)shippingBtnAction:(id)sender
   {

   UIButton* btn = (UIButton*)sender;
   btn.selected  = ! btn.selected;
   if (btn.isSelected)
   {
       _isDefaultShipping = 1;
       [self.shippingBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
   else
   {
       _isDefaultShipping = 0;
       [self.shippingBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }

   }
   ```